# Accessing on-premises web service from Azure websites

Tags: web-services, azure

We currently have a large array of customers (1000 different on-premises installations).

We use a single server to host our sites which communicates with on-premises WebAPI's.

Currently we limit the traffic to the local servers in the router to allow only our server to access the local API's.

However we are considering moving alot of these webservices/sites to Azure which in turn means limiting on the IP's addresses becomes not feasible.

What approach would you recommend to allow the Azure servers to access the on-premises servers?

Best case scenario would of course be that no ports needed to be open in the routers (limit maintenance) however this seems very hard to accomplish if we still would like the ease of development that WebAPI gives us.

Otherwise we have thought about opening for public access to the API's but securing with https and authentication.

Does anyone have any alternative solutions?

Note: The on-premises WebAPI services are hosted with selfhost inside a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using '[Azure Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview)' to access your on-premises Web API.

You could host your websites as 'Web Apps' in Azure App service and access your Web API. 
You do not need to open any firewall ports or change your network perimeter configuration to allow any inbound connectivity into your network